# Force views to write exposed form block info to {block} table during install profile

Tags: 7, views, blocks, database, installation-profiles

In a D7 install profile, I am trying to modify the location of a exposed filter block with `db_update()`, where the view is defined by a module's `hook_views_default_views()`.

At this point it doesn't seem views has collected the views from `hook_views_default_views()` or the view block does not exist (or db_update cannot address it) in the {block} table until I actually bootstrap Drupal after installation is complete. I have attempted:

- Invalidating the views cache via `views_invalidate_cache()`
- Loading the view with `views_get_view(NAME)`
- Triggering `drupal_cron_run()`

Before issuing the `db_update()` with no success. I am not versed enough in views to understand at what point views writes the exposed filter blocks to the block table, or how to force it to do so.

I am employing `'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE`, during my `db_update()` call.

Update : doing a views_get_view() cannot actually load the view. It appears that install profiles do not have access to views provided by hook_default_views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a views_get_view() cannot actually load the view. From what I can tell, it appears that install profiles do not have access to views provided by hook_default_views.